# Fechar sistema após fechar Dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Como posso fazer com que uma tela de login ao ser fechada, feche também todo o sistema?

No código abaixo eu tenho uma tela principal com o botão "mudar usuário", ao clicar, o sistema abre um `Dialog` para o novo usuário fazer login, porém se o usuário fechar o `Dialog`, ele continua com acesso ao sistema e eu gostaria que ao fechar o `Dialog`, todo o sistema seja fechado.

Tentei mudar o código de `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` para `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` mas o sistema me apresenta um erro:

> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultCloseOperation must be one
>   of: DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE, HIDE_ON_CLOSE, or DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE".

**Código tela principal**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TPrincipal extends JFrame {

    private TPrincipal getInstance() {
        return this;
    }

    public TPrincipal() {
        setTitle("Frame principal");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnFrame = new JButton("Mudar Usuário");
        btnFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //passando a instancia do Frame para referencia do modal
                new TLogin(getInstance()).start();
            }

        });
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JLabel("Este é o frame principal"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btnFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TPrincipal().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Código tela de login**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class TLogin extends JDialog {

    public TLogin(TPrincipal owner) {
        super(owner, "Dialog 02", true);
    }

    public void start() {
        add(new JLabel("Esta é a segunda janela modal"));
        JButton btnFrame = new JButton("LOGIN REALIZADO - Fechar apenas modal");
        btnFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //login realizado com sucesso
            }
        });
        setSize(300, 300);
        add(btnFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(getParent());
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja as duas perguntas marcadas como duplicatas. Acredito que nelas tem a soluçao pra sua duvida.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, porem não consigo definir EXIT_ON_CLOSE em um JDialog, por se tratar de um modal de login, preciso que ao fechar o modal, todo o sistema feche (exceto se login for efetuado).

Comment: Ernani, apresente um **[mcve]** do seu código para que possamos executar, reabrir e sugerir algo melhor. Sem um exemplo que qualquer um possa executar nao tem como te ajudar.

Comment: Ernani seu codigo nao reflete o problema da pergunta. Cade a tela de login? Cade a validacao de login que deve fechar tudo se nao ocorrer corretamente? Esse exemplo nao tem praticamente nada a ver com a duvida.

Comment: A questão não é validação de usuário, é sobre o usuário clicar no "X" da aba do Dialog e todo o sistema não ser fechado junto, mesmo se JDialog setado como EXIT_ON_CLOSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para forçar o fechamento de toda a aplicaçao quando a janela modal ser fechada no <kbd>x</kbd> da janela, pode adicionar um `WindowListener` e sobrescrever o método `windowClosed()`, que é chamado quando se tenta fechar desta forma.

```
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]